# Function triggered two times

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have a class written in Node.js but when I trigger a function inside the class it runs the console.log two times.

```
class Client{

    constructor(){
        this.test();
    }

    test(){
        console.log("testing");
    }
}

var RR = new Client;
RR.test();
```

I appreciate all the help, I think It will be common sense for you but I am not able to solve it.

Console output:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\NodeRR>node index.js
test
test
```

Comment: The constructor of a class is called each time a new instance of that class is created `new Client;` in this case.

Comment: When you create new obj, you call the constructor which calls the method. Then you call the method again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
constructor(){
        this.test();
    }
```

This part of the code is calling the test method when creating a new object, and then you're calling it again in the line

```
RR.test();
```

Either remove the constructor call, or your own call. It will then run a single time as required by you.

Comment: Solved, thanks you! I know It was an idiot question but I'm learning

Comment: @PepB no problem, we all are learning at the same time. Please do select/accept the answer if you can!

Comment: I'm waiting for that. I need to wait 15 minutes

Answer (score 3):

The method `test`is being invoked on the constructor, so when you create the new instance, the constructor is called and the method invoked.

If you don't want it to be called twice, remove it from your constructor and use the `RR.test();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you call the test() function in the constructor. So when you do `new Client()` it call the constructor. And then you call `RR.test()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method `Client#test` both from the class' `constructor` method and from the given reference to this instance. You can solve this problem by either removing the line `this.test();` from `Client` class' constructor or by removing the line `RR.test();` from your script.